# How do I concatenate 2 variable names into 1 name in TCL?

Tags: tcl

I've got a group of variables that are lists of bytes that I'm trying to search through.

```
set foo0 [list 0 1 2]
set foo1 [list 3 4 5]
set foo2 [list 6 7 8]
set fooCount 3

for { set z 0 } { $z<$fooCount} { incr z } { 
    tbf str "foo$z: foo$z"
}
```

I'd like this to print out:

```
foo0: 0 1 2
foo1: 3 4 5
foo2: 6 7 8
```

But I get:

```
foo0: foo0
foo1: foo1
foo2: foo2
```

I tried changing my print line to

```
tbf str "foo$z: $foo$z"
```

But then I get an error that there is no variable foo.  I've also tried copying all of the foo variables into a fooList, but again I don't seem to be getting the contents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
tbf str "foo$z: [set foo$z]"
```

The `set` command returns the value of that token, which is `foo0`, `foo1` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays, it's easy too:

```
set foo(0) [list 0 1 2]
set foo(1) [list 3 4 5]
set foo(2) [list 6 7 8]
set fooCount 3

for { set z 0 } { $z<$fooCount} { incr z } { 
    tbf str "foo($z): $foo($z)"
}
```

Comment: In my case, I'm actually importing the foo variables so I'm stuck with those foo<n> names.  Thanks for the answer.